# Facebook Custom URL Scheme in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook

Does the facebook custom url scheme still work? I am currently trying to publish to the native facebook app using

```
fb://publish/profile/me?text=%@
```

but it does not work. It just opens the facebook app.